# How to run casperJS script from php API

Tags: php, javascript, api, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a casperJS script which returns JSON when run via commandline. I want to make an API preferably in PHP which runs the script as in commandline (casperJS sample.js) and returns the JSON as result.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use php exec() function as shown below to do this

```
echo exec("/home/user/casperjs/bin/casperjs /full/path/to/your_script.js");
```

Comment: Awesome! Just wondering how do you pass value on each exec? Cause I need to pass a unique search term.

Comment: @3zzy You could pass it as command line arguments `echo exec("/home/user/casperjs/bin/casperjs /full/path/to/your_script.js arg1 arg2");` , read more about casperjs command line arguments [here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html)

Comment: Ah man, a bit late. I spent like a day setting up PHP-Casper which is okay but too slow and doesn't work with `nohup` .. Will try this, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [php-casperjs](https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs) library which is a simple wrapper for `casperjs`.